# netbeans creates trunk folder on uploading files

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to upload files into my host.

To configure uploading file in netbeans project I tried this:

->right click on project/properties/Run Configuration

> project URL:   C:\wamp\www\obe\trunk(index.php)//here is index files
>
> Upload folder: /OBE/(index.php)//here is index files

The problem is when I want to upload file it creates trunk folder on live so the upload root path is  : /OBE/trunk/(index.php)//here is index files

Any idea how to get read of this trunk folder?